# Why foreign key is null? @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate-onetomany

I created two entities: Customer and Car. I used relation @OneToMany because i wanted assign few         cars to one customer in database with foreign key user_id.
I saved everything to database and I don;t know why in table with cars where there is column with
user_id it shows me only nulls.

CustomerCarsService:

```java
@Service
public class CustomerCarsService {

    public CustomerCarsService(CarRepository carRepository, CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        Customer customerAnnaMazurek = new Customer();
        customerAnnaMazurek.setNameAndSurname("Anna Mazurek");
        customerAnnaMazurek.setAge(50);
        customerRepository.save(customerAnnaMazurek);

        Customer customerJanMazurek = new Customer();
        customerJanMazurek.setNameAndSurname("Jan Mazurek");
        customerJanMazurek.setAge(70);
        customerRepository.save(customerJanMazurek);


        Car lamboCar = new Car();
        lamboCar.setMarka("Lambo");
        lamboCar.setModel("Hurracan");
        lamboCar.setMaxSpeed(350);
        carRepository.save(lamboCar);

        Car ferrariCar = new Car();
        ferrariCar.setMarka("Ferrari");
        ferrariCar.setModel("Portofino");
        ferrariCar.setMaxSpeed(350);
        carRepository.save(ferrariCar);

        Car huandayCar = new Car();
        huandayCar.setMarka("Huanday");
        huandayCar.setModel("Pipo");
        huandayCar.setMaxSpeed(300);
        carRepository.save(huandayCar);

        List<Car> annaMazurekCars = new ArrayList<>();
        annaMazurekCars.add(lamboCar);
        annaMazurekCars.add(ferrariCar);
        customerAnnaMazurek.setCarList(annaMazurekCars);

        List<Car> janMazurekCars = new ArrayList<>();
        janMazurekCars.add(lamboCar);
        janMazurekCars.add(ferrariCar);
        janMazurekCars.add(huandayCar);
        customerJanMazurek.setCarList(janMazurekCars);


      }
   }
```

Customer Entity:

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "customers")
    public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String nameAndSurname;
    private Integer age;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private List<Car> cars;


    public Customer() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNameAndSurname() {
        return nameAndSurname;
    }

    public void setNameAndSurname(String nameAndSurname) {
        this.nameAndSurname = nameAndSurname;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public List<Car> getCarList() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCarList(List<Car> carList) {
        this.cars = carList;
    }
}
```

Car Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    private String marka;
    private String model;
    private double maxSpeed;

    public Car() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMarka() {
        return marka;
    }

    public void setMarka(String marka) {
        this.marka = marka;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public double getMaxSpeed() {
        return maxSpeed;
    }

    public void setMaxSpeed(double maxSpeed) {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even `customerRepository.flush()` at the end should be enough, because after save the objects are in managed state.

Answer (score 0):

try to save your customers

```
    customerRepository.save(customerJanMazurek);
    customerRepository.save(customerAnnaMazurek);
```